# Using font awesome with formtastic submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome, formtastic

I have a submit button on my form:

```
= semantic_form_for record do |form|
  = form.actions do
    = form.submit 'Save'
```

I want to add an icon from FontAwesome, with `link_to` I can use a block:

```
= link_to record do
  = fa_icon 'save'
  Save
```

But this doesn't work with Formtastic's `form.submit`.

I also tried:

```
= form.submit fa_icon('save')
= form.submit fa_icon('save').html_safe
```

But both renders escaped HTML.

How do I add a font-awesome icon to the `<button>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`capture`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) to set a label, as in:

```
- label = capture do
  = fa_icon 'save'
  Save
= form.button label
```

This only seems to work for `form.button`, but not for `form.submit.` You'll have to use `form.button label, type: :submit`.