# Add fa fa icon to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I want to add a font-awesome icon to my link to items.

I am struggling to add this

```
<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
```

to this:

```
 buttons = content_tag(:li) do
      link_to(env[:environment], deployment_results_path(:project=> project, :environment=> env[:environment]))

     end
     concat buttons
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Very similar: [Using font awesome with formtastic submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24460266/660921)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link_to( ("<i class='fa fa-cloud'></i>" + env[:environment]).html_safe, 
          deployment_results_path(:project=> project, 
                                  :environment=> env[:environment]))
```